# Entity Framework Core TPH Inheritance 2 sub Classes related to Other Model

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am devoloping an Asp.Net Core 3 App with Entity Framework Core.

I have a problem with Inheritance and I am not sure how to accomplish what I need.

My Models:

```
public abstract class Person
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string name {get; set;}
}

public class Renter: Person
{
   public string address{get; set;}
   public ICollection<Invoice> Invoices{get;set;}
}

public class UserProfile: Person
{
   public string BankAccount {get;set;}
   public ICollection<Invoice> Invoices{get;set;}
}

public class Invoice
{
   public DateTime Date {get;set;}

   public Renter Renter {get; set;}
   
   [Required]
   public int RenterId {get; set;}

   public UserProfile UserProfile{get; set;}
   
   [Required]
   public int UserProfileId {get; set;}
}
```

Right Now I get a Database Exception: Foreign Key Constraint Fails : RenterId References Person.Id .
Can I Use Fluent Api to manually configure my Setup?
The problem is that the Invoice needs both a Renter and a UserProfile, but Person.Id is the Primary Key for both Renter and UserProfile.

Any help is gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use fluent API. Assuming that you are using Table per Type (TPT):

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  modelBuilder.Entity<Renter>().ToTable("Renter");
  modelBuilder.Entity<UserProfile>().ToTable("UserProfile");
}
```

See: https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/inheritance-strategy-in-code-first.aspx